# Is it appropriate to display the dojo kun at home?

Tags: karate, dojo, etiquette

The [dojo kun](http://www.iskf.com/dojo%20kun.html) is a set of 5 principles that should be followed in the dojo. The dojo kun states the basic philosophy of karate, according to Funakoshi. Some schools choose to recite the principles at the end of each training session.

The principles are in Japanese, and translate to:

> - Seek Perfection of Character
> - Be faithful
> - Endeavor
> - Respect Others
> - Refrain from Violent Behavior

Would it be appropriate to display these rules through work of art or crafts in a home environment as well? I just really appreciate the philosophy behind them, yet they are explicitly linked to the dojo. I couldn't find anything arguing against home-use via a web search. However, I also couldn't find anything arguing *for* it either.

<sub>Source: [ISKF](http://www.iskf.com/dojo%20kun.html)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

Of course it is appropriate.

I am struggling to find a reason why not to do it if you are keen on it. [It is a piece of nice calligraphy](http://www.iskf.com/images/dojo%20kun.png) which would be enough to display as an art piece regardless of whether you abide by it or not.

Besides, it is your home and you should be able to decorate it how you see it.

I could not find a higher resolution image of it but you probably can buy prints of it from somewhere (ISKF site?) or get some ink, brushes, and do one yourself.

Comment: I would like to add emphasis to Sardathrion's statement about it being entirely up to you how you decorate your own home. Seriously, the only opinions which should matter in this case are one's own and those of anyone you share a living space with.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, in the spirit of the question, that it should be treated with appropriate respect. While I agree with Sardathrion that it is up to you how you decorate your home, the fact that you are asking suggests that you care about "proper" approach to such symbol/item.

Although not Karate practitioner myself, from my own experience with this kind of items in Japanese culture, I would require of myself to put it in an appropriate room, in a place that grants proper respect to it (so, not nailed through to a wall next to a Playboy calendar) etc.

I would actually be wary of putting this kind of item in my house, as I would (personally!) feel obligated to keep at least the room in a clean and orderly state. Though maybe it is precisely why I should. Something like: if you were to display urn of ashes of your family members, you would not probably want it to be surrounded with trash, dust and general mess. The respect shown is not to the item, it is respect shown to the idea behind it.